# How to get start day and end day of a particular month and year in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Iam having the `month` value like `(1 to 12)` and `year` value like `2011 to 2012` by passing these parameters i want to get the `starting day` and `ending day` of the paticular `month` and `year`. how can i do this in ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Date.civil` sounds like what you need

```
start_date = Date.civil(2011, 1, 1)  #=> Sat, 01 Jan 2011
end_date = Date.civil(2011, 12, -1)   #=> Sat, 31 Dec 2011
```

Docs: [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-civil)

Comment: You can also use `Date.new(...)` (`civil` is an alias for `new`)

Comment: Good catch, didnt think of that when i wrote my example. I'll edit that in just in case!

Answer (score 8):

In addition to jfornoff's excellent answer, Rails' *Active Support* gem comes with a rich set of [date and time methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date' #to cherry pick just date helpers

d = Date.new(2011, 4)  #=> Fri, 01 Apr 2011

d.beginning_of_month   #=> Fri, 01 Apr 2011
d.end_of_month         #=> Sat, 30 Apr 2011
d.all_month            #=> Fri, 01 Apr 2011..Sat, 30 Apr 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date' 

start_date = Date.new(2016, 2)
  #=> #<Date: 2016-02-01 ((2457420j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
end_date = (start_date >> 1) - 1
  #=> #<Date: 2016-02-29 ((2457448j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```